# Realtime MessageConsole GUI in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, console, jtextarea

I have to insert a GUI Console in my Java application.

I have chosen [MessageConsole.java](http://pastebin.com/i6x34DGE) class to do this.

In my app I use this code to use the class :

```
logPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea (28,90);
    textArea.setEditable (false);
    textArea.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    logPanel.add(new JScrollPane (
            textArea, 
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED),
        BorderLayout.CENTER);
    MessageConsole mc = new MessageConsole(textArea);
    mc.redirectOut();
    mc.redirectErr(Color.RED, null);
    mc.setMessageLines(999);
```

Unfortunately, the doesn't work as I want. The messages lines appears when the app is in "pause" (waiting for user interaction). What I want is the lines appears one by one like the usual console, because for the moment a thousand of lines appear in the same time...

I looked for some "delay" in the MessageConsole class, but didn't find it.

My question is how to get my message lines in real time ?

Thank you.

Comment: The issue may be elsewhere in your code. How are you handling Swing threading issues? Are you careful to do background processes in a background thread? To change the state of Swing components on the Swing event thread only? These details are crucial.

Comment: To use the console in the main method of the app, I call a UI class which creates the JFrame (UI window = new UI()). The rest of the code is in the UI method of the UI class, that's all. I thought the MessageConsole class could check this change of Swing state... So no i don't have any background process in the app.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought the MessageConsole class could check this change of Swing state

The MessageConsole class will redirect system output to the textarea (or textpane). However, the [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) is like any Swing component. You need to update the console with code executing on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Here is a simple example of executing code on the EDT by using a Swing Timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println( new java.util.Date().toString() );
    }
});
timer.start();
```

> a thousand of lines appear in the same time

This means that you have long running code executing on the EDT so the GUI can't repaint itself until the entire code is finished executing. So the long running code needs to execute in a separate Thread or maybe a SwingWorker. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.